# $\lnot\exists x(S(x) \Rightarrow R(x))$ VS $\forall x(S(x) \Rightarrow R(x))$ Without Using De Morgan's Law

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I was doing logic exercises the other day and I encountered the following:

> Write this statement symbolically and verify your answer using De Morgan's Law:
>
> No squares are rectangles

My solution:

Let $R(x): x$ is a rectangle and $S(x): x$ is a square. Now, we know none of the squares are rectangles; so in other words, there doesn't exist a square that's also a rectangle. I thought the following would be the its equivalent: $\lnot\exists x(S(x) \Rightarrow R(x))$ but I also thought, can't we say all squares are not rectangles and so I wrote the following:  $\forall x(S(x) \Rightarrow \lnot R(x))$ but using De Morgan's law, these two are obviously not equivalent and only the latter is right. Could you explain,without using De Morgan's Law, why the first statement is wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Mathematicians usually consider $x$ and $X$ to be different symbols. You seem to be using them rather interchangeably.

Comment: Could you please explain?EDIT: Is it better now?

Comment: Well, you fixed it now, so it's fine.

Comment: >"but I also thought, can't we say all squares are not rectangles and so I wrote the following: $\forall x(S(x)\implies R(x))$"

Where was the "not" in that sentence? I think you meant to say $\forall x (S(x)\implies \neg R(x))$.

Comment: @JackCrawford yes, thank you. I fixed it.

Comment: See also the post [Representing the statement using Quantifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369546/representing-the-statement-using-quantifiers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No squares are rectangles

is the same as "There is no object that is both a Square and a Rectangle".

Thus, in symbols :

> $¬∃x(S(x) \land R(x))$;

This in turn is equivalent to :

> $∀x(S(x) \to ¬R(x))$,

and this is exactly : "All squares are not rectangles".

The quantifiers equivalence : $\lnot \exists \equiv \forall \lnot$ is one of the most intuitive logical equivalence : if there is **no** Black swan, then all swans are **not**-Black (and vice versa).

The next step needs the propositional equivalence is : $\lnot (p \land q) \equiv (p \to \lnot q)$.

---

---

Let's start with : "All squares are not rectangles".

What about if there is an object $a$ that is a Triangle ? It is neither a Square nor a Rectangle, and thus $S(a) \to ¬R(a)$ is True ($\text F \to \text T = \text T$).

This means that the object $a$ does not contradict the formula $∀x(S(x) \to ¬R(x))$.

What happens with $¬∃x(S(x) \land R(x))$ ? We have that $S(a) \land R(a)$ is False, and thus we have no issue also with $¬∃x(S(x) \land R(x))$.

But what about $¬∃x(S(x) \to R(x))$ ?

We have that $S(a) \to R(a)$ is True, and thus the Triangle $a$ satisfy the formula $∃x(S(x) \to R(x))$.

This means that the existence of the Triangle $a$ contradicts the formula $¬∃x(S(x) \to R(x))$, and this means that this formula is not equivalent to : "All squares are not rectangles", and thus is not equivalent to "No squares are rectangles" either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I said, I already know what the answer is but why isn't $\lnot\exists x(S(x) \Rightarrow R(x))$ a valid answer?I know it can be easily proven using De Morgan's law but could you explain why it's not a valid answer without using other statements?

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade An $x$ which is neither a square nor a rectangle satisfies $S(x)\Rightarrow R(x)$. So your statement also means that such an $x$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

$S(x)\Rightarrow R(x)$ is always true when $S(x)$ is false, that is, when $x$ isn't a square. Therefore the statement $\neg \exists x (S(x)\Rightarrow R(x)) $ would imply, among other things, that there is no object which isn't a square. This is clearly not a conseqence of what you want to convey. As long as there exists object that isn't a square, its existance makes the statement $\neg \exists x (S(x)\Rightarrow R(x)) $ false, but it doesn't falsify the statement "no squares are rectangles".