# Determine the truth value of $(\forall x)(\exists y)(x=y\to x>y)$ over the integers

Tags: proof-verification, logic

> Determine the truth value of $$(\forall x)(\exists y)(x=y\to x>y)$$ over the integers.

My work:

$(\forall x)(\exists y)(x=y\to x>y)$ means "For all $x$, there exists a $y$ where $x=y\to x>y$".

Since $x=y$, we can replace the $y$ with the $x$ and vice-versa. We can get $$x>x$$ once we replaced.

This statement is always false, no matter what $x$ is. So in this case $x=y$ is true, but $x>y$ is not true, or false. So, using the truth table below, $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}x=y&x>y&x=y\to x>y\\\hline\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}\\\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}\\\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}\\\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}\end{array}$$ we can say that this statement is false.

[(Image that replaced text).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTnPB.png)

Comment: What you wrote in that solution explains why $x=y\to x>y$ is not always true. So that shows that $\forall x\forall y(x=y\to x>y)$  is false, but it doesn't say anything about the given problem.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean your solution is wrong.

Comment: Ohhh. So how do I prove that (∀x)(∃y)(=→>) is false?

Comment: You don't. It's true.

Comment: Sorry for asking this again, but how do I show that?

Comment: Would I use contradiction?

Comment: What was wrong about the first solution was you sort of missed the point to the $\forall x\exists y$ part (the "quantifiers"). Here's an outline of the solution that deals properly with the quantifiers, with blanks you should be able to fill in: "Given $x$, let $y=\dots$. Then ..., so $x=y\to x>y$ is true."

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $\forall x~\color{red}\exists y~(P(x,y)\to Q(x,y))$ is true exactly when: every $x$ has *some* $y$ where $Q(x,y)$ is true *or* $P(x,y)$ is false.

---

> Since $x=y$, we can replace the $y$ with the $x$ and vice-versa. We can get $$x>x$$ once we replaced.
>
> This statement is always false, no matter what $x$ is. So in this case $x=y$ is true, but $x>y$ is not true, or false. So, using the truth table below, $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}x=y&x>y&x=y\to x>y\\\hline\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}\\\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}\\\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}\\\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}\end{array}$$ we can say that this statement is false.

No.  What the truth table is telling you is that the implication is *true* in three cases.

Case 1: $x=y$ and $x>y$. Well, for any $x$ that cannot happen. However we must check the other two cases.

Case 2: $\lnot(x=y)$ and $x>y$.  Well, for any $x$ there is *some* $y$ where both of these are true.

Case 3: $\lnot (x=y)$ and $\lnot(x>y)$.  Well, for any $x$ there is *some* $y$ where both of these are true.

Since for any $x$ there is a $y$ where $\lnot (x=y)$, then cases $2$ and $3$ may be satisfied for any $x$. Thus we *confirm* that for any $x$ there is *some* $y$ where the implication holds.

Answer (score 1):

If $P(x)$ is false for some $x$, then $P(x) \to Q(x)$ is true no matter what the value of $Q(x)$ is so if you find an $y$ where $y \neq x$(e.g $x-1$), the statement would always hold.

Also, this is related:  [$\lnot\exists x(S(x) \Rightarrow R(x))$ VS $\forall x(S(x) \Rightarrow R(x))$ Without Using De Morgan's Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236947/lnot-exists-xsx-rightarrow-rx-vs-forall-xsx-rightarrow-rx-wi)